# Which is induced first EMF or Electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I am quite amazed by the reasoning given by my teacher about induced electric field and induced EMF.Well,the case was of a closed conducting loop placed in a time varying but uniform(in space) magnetic field.

He said that that EMF is induced first that's why a non conservative and non electrostatic electric field is induced which drives the free electrons in the loop.

I think that electric field is induced first which is responsible for the induction of EMF in the loop!

Please explain which is induced first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they are the same thing, so its simultaneous.

Consider Maxwell's Equation:

$$\nabla \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

Our Electric field has a non-zero vector derivative if we have a time varying Magnetic field.

EMF is equal to the negative time derivative of the Magnetic flux:

$$\epsilon=-\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}=-\frac{d}{dt}\int\vec{B}\cdot \hat{n} \ dA$$

Where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal to the plane of the current loop, and $dA$ is differential area. Assuming space invariance of a time varying field, the time derivative can be taken into the integral and applied to the magnetic field before performing the integral.

Then we can apply Stoke's Theorem.

$$\int -\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \hat{n} dA=\int(\nabla \times \vec{E})\cdot \hat{n} dA=\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=\epsilon$$

The EMF is the line integral, but the line integral is the area integral of the vector space derivative, or curl, of the Electric Field.